# Count number of occurrences of array elements

Tags: c, arrays

I am stuck in a situation. My problem is to get the most repeated number in an integer array which can have values from 0 to 5,000. The number should at least be repeated *n*/4 number of times, where *n* is the array length.

I had a look at extracting at least *n*/2  times repeated element. But I couldn't modify that to my requirement. Also, since mine is not character array, I can't create an array of 5,000 size to increment the index of the repeated number.

Comment: _I can't create an array of 5000 size to increment the index of the repeated number._: why not?

Comment: @hmjd - because i am programming in embedded environment where there is limitation of RAM size, mine is 6kB.

Comment: If that's the case then how are you going to read the input array which is about 5000*4 bytes = 19kb?

Comment: @KingsIndian - The range of each number inputted is `[0,5000]`. But the number of numbers inputted is just `n` (as per OP).

Comment: 0-5000 value range needs at least 13-bit. 13-bit*5000=65000 bit which is nearly 8kb even if you dont waste a single bit. To fit it inside 6kb, you need to compress it.

Comment: my array is 32 elements in which each element can vary from 0 to 5000.

Comment: So, you want the number repeated 8 times

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how I would approach this, I think this makes sense for this kind of problem:

1. Sort the array (in place), trivial using `qsort()` if you have it, of course.
2. Iterate through, keeping a counter that you reset every time the array value changes, and once the counter hits n/4, remember which number it did so for.
3. Done.

The important thing here is that the sorting makes it trivial to count each element at a time, by grouping all the identical elements together into a single sequence, which makes the counting trivial.

Comment: I suppose that works, I will come back give a thumbs up if it does practically. Thanks

Comment: But OP asks for number of occurances not the consequtively repeatings.

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık After sorting, that's the same thing. All occurances will be grouped into a single sequence. Example: `[1, 5, 4, 3, 1, 7, 2, 1]` -> [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]`.

Comment: YEs. That saves a lot of ram without using different counters. +1

Comment: thank you very much unwind... but what if for ex, 2047 is repeated 16 times and 2012 is repeated 10 times, this algorithm returns 2012 since it first finds it, but most repeated element is 2047. any ideas ?

Comment: @Chaithra Edit your question to reflect the need to find the _most_ repeated number _that is also_ appearing in more than n/4 places.